# MongoDB - custom sort aggregation with embedded doccument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation

The `application` collection includes `status` field and an embedded `offer` field which has a `status` field as well. an `application` might come with no `offer`.

The conditions I have to consider to sort is a bit complicated.

The order has to be:

1st: Applications with Offer and the Offer status is `pending`

2nd: Applications with no Offer and any value for status except these: `rejected`, `assigned`, `accepted`

3rd: Applications with Offer and the offer status is: `rejected`

4th: Applications with Offer and the offer status is: `withdrawn`

5th: other cases

---

The query I am trying is this:

```
db.application.aggregate([
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "job": 1,
        "offer": 1,
        "user": 1,
        "denormalized": 1,
        "custom_sort": {
            $cond: {
                if: { $eq: ["offer.$status", "pending"] }, then: 1,
                else: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: { $ne: ["$status", ["rejected", "assigned", "accepted"]] }, then: 2,
                        else: {
                            $cond: {
                                if: { $eq: ["offer$status", "rejected"] }, then: 3,
                                else: {
                                    $cond: {
                                        if: { $eq: ["offer$status", "withdrawn"] }, then: 4,
                                        else: 5
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
{"$sort": {"custom_sort": 1}},
{ "$project": { "_id": 1, "status": 1, "job": 1, "offer": 1, "user": 1, "denormalized": 1, "custom_sort": 1 } }
])
```

The Query works. But, not as expected.
There are two problems I have:

1- If application does not have offer, the first condition will be ignored

2- how can I use `and` or `or` in if conditions

Some sample application documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f0c8c517587d306033f9f2"),
    "status" : "new",
    "offer" : {
        "status" : "withdrawn"
    }
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f0b38517587d29bb1eb6b3"),
    "status" : "new",
    "offer" : {
        "status" : "rejected"
    }
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f0b35717587d29bb1eb6b2"),
    "status" : "new",
    "offer" : {
        "status" : "pending"
    }
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58de110e46fc387b39744285"),
    "status" : "rejected"
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58de119946fc3876035f823c"),
    "status" : "new"
}
```

Comment: Is the "conditions you have to consider"  actually the order of documents you expect?

Comment: @AlexBlex. Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [$and and $or operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-boolean/) you can use in if conditions, but you don't need them in this particulr case.

You will be better with [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/#exp._S_switch) case:

```
    "custom_sort": { $cond: {
        if: { $eq: [ { $type: "$offer" }, "object" ] }, 
        then: { $switch: {
            branches: [
                { case: { $eq: [ "$offer.status", "pending" ] }, then: 1 },
                { case: { $eq: [ "$offer.status", "rejected" ] }, then: 3 },
                { case: { $eq: [ "$offer.status", "withdrawn" ] }, then: 4 },
            ],
            default: 5
        } },
        else: { $cond : {
            if: { $in: [ "$status", [ "rejected", "assigned", "accepted" ] ] },
            then: 2,
            else: 5
        } }
    } }
```

Comment: Thanks man. I know about `$and` and `$or`. But, the fact is aggregation does not allow to use them directly. I made some more changes which almost did it. But, I still was missing the part you fixed it by using `$type`. You saved me ;)